# How to move Docker containers between different hosts?

Tags: docker, containers, docker-registry

I cannot find a way of moving docker running containers from one host to another.

Is there any way I can push my containers to repositories like we do for images ?
Currently, I am not using data volumes to store the data associated with applications running inside containers. So some data resides inside containers, which I want to persist before redesigning the setup.

Comment: Have a look at flocker https://github.com/ClusterHQ/flocker

Comment: Note that you may wish to use save/load instead of export/import, as save preserves metadata and history.

Comment: Should this be a comment to @aholt's answer?

Comment: `docker save` is for saving images, not containers. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You cannot move a running docker container from one host to another.

You can commit the changes in your container to an image with [`docker commit`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/), move the image onto a new host, and then start a new container with [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/).  This will preserve any data that your application has created inside the container.

**NB:** It does not preserve data that is stored inside volumes; you need to move data volumes manually to new host.

Comment: docker-checkpoint could let you move a "running" container between hosts, if they both support CRIU.

Comment: @DaveJarvis if you want to make that extensive of an edit I would suggest simply posting  a new answer.

Comment: I moved Lau's helpful comment into a more visible location. I thought the idea of a wiki was that anyone could edit an answer to improve it?

Comment: This isn't a wiki, and when you make major changes to someone else's answer you're putting words into their mouth. Editing a question to make minor correction is just fine, but if you need to add substantial new information it's generally better to just post a new answer (and consider adding a comment on the accepted answer pointing at the additional information).

Comment: So, "Here's an answer, with no steps on how to accomplish it, and a vague warning that there's something else you may need to do, also with no steps on how to do that."

Comment: @JohnSmith I'm glad this almost-10-year-old answer was moving enough to inspire a comment!

Answer (score 135):

Alternatively, if you do not wish to push to a repository:

1. Export the container to a tarball

   ```
   docker export <CONTAINER ID> > /home/export.tar
   ```
2. Move your tarball to new machine
3. Import it back

   ```
   cat /home/export.tar | docker import - some-name:latest
   ```

Comment: Also does not preserve data that is stored inside volumes.

Comment: How is this supposed to work? After the import I get new image, and then what? Just do a new run command?

Comment: This is actually a really bad suggestion, especially for containers running database. I tried this suggestion and it didn't work. Could it maybe work with stopping container first?

Comment: This suggestion was only really meant for an alternative.  It might work for your situation, it might not.  For me, I was setting up database replication docker containers at the time, and for the export/import, did not care about preserving the data, as I was running backups of the database data regularly out to a different tarball.  For that, this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 69):

What eventually worked for me, after lot's of confusing manuals and confusing tutorials, since Docker is obviously at time of my writing at [peak of inflated expectations](https://www.gartner.com/technology/research/methodologies/hype-cycle.jsp), is:

1. Save the docker image into archive:
   `docker save image_name > image_name.tar`
2. copy on another machine
3. on that other docker machine, run docker load in a following way:
   `cat image_name.tar | docker load`

Export and import, as proposed in another answers does not export ports and variables, which might be required for your container to run. And you might end up with stuff like **"No command specified"** etc... When you try to load it on another machine.

So, difference between save and export is that save command saves whole image with history and metadata, while export command exports only files structure (without history or metadata).

Needless to say is that, if you already have those ports taken on the docker hyper-visor you are doing import, by some other docker container, you will end-up in conflict, and you will have to reconfigure exposed ports.

Note: In order to move data with docker, you might be having persistent storage somewhere, which should also be moved alongside with containers.

*Update 10/2023*
**Another very good way to migrate docker containers**
You can actually follow [this upgrade script](https://gist.github.com/marcelrv/e7dac93863945dccc46f70915c84b5db), but modified
for moving instead of upgrading.  You will also ***need docker compose on target machine***.

1. Use autocompose.py from https://github.com/Red5d/docker-autocompose/ you can use it as docker container also

```
    cd ~
    mkdir ~/dockercontainers
    sudo docker container list -a > ~/dockercontainers/containers.txt
    cat  ~/dockercontainers/containers.txt
    
    CIDS=$(docker container list -a | sed '1d' | awk '{print $1}')
    for c in $CIDS; do mkdir ~/dockercontainers/$c ; docker run --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ghcr.io/red5d/docker-autocompose $c > ~/dockercontainers/$c/docker-compose.yml ; done
```

2. Inspect composer files and move volume folders with data on new machine
3. Export Images and tags as txt files **Images**: `mkdir dockersave && docker images > dockersave/images.txt`   **tags**: `cat dockersave/images.txt | sed '1d'  | awk '{ print "docker tag "$3" "$1":"$2 }'>> tags.txt`
4. Perform actual Images export (you can commit them before this step if required)  `IDS=$(docker images | sed '1d' | awk '{print $3}') for c in $IDS; do docker save -o dockersave/$c.tar $c; done`
5. Copy everything from dockersave and dockercontainers to target machine.
6. Load images onto new docker:
   `cd dockersave/ IDS=$(ls *.tar) for c in $IDS; do docker load -i $c; done`
7. Restore containers `CIDS=$(cat ~/dockercontainers/containers.txt | sed '1d' | awk '{print $1}'); for c in $CIDS; do cd ~/dockercontainers/$c ; docker-compose up -d --no-deps --build ; done`

If everything is fine, you will get bunch of OK messages and docker ps will display all of your containers.

Comment: Hugely helpful.  The "No command specified" message was driving me crazy.

Comment: The "No command specified" message was driving me crazy too. I use docker commit <container-id> stackstorm-local:2.9, and docker pull stackstorm-local:2.9 from another host.

Comment: same here, you just saved my container and my time !

Comment: It should be noted that before doing the  `docker save` and `docker load`, one should commit the container to the image `sudo docker commit <container_id> image_name`

Comment: No, no, no. All the save/load procedure above did was create an unusably broken container on the destination machine. It loads, starts, runs, all without any errors, and then, when you try to use it, it's like it's not even there, it just plain doesn't work at all, it's like it's not running. It works 100% as expected on the machine saved from, and not at all on the destination.

Comment: What did work, though, was zipping the /var/lib/docker folder into an archive, copying, expanding it on the destination machine. Boom, done, everything works. Why people give all sorts of nonworking hoops to jump through and never mention this simple working solution, I have no idea.

Comment: @JohnSmith I guess that your solution works if there are no containers on target host already running...

Comment: This never uses the created tags.txt, resulting in refetching of the images

Answer (score 33):

Use this script:
https://github.com/ricardobranco777/docker-volumes.sh

This *does* preserve data in volumes.

Example usage:

```shell
# Stop the container   
docker stop $CONTAINER

# Create a new image   
docker commit $CONTAINER $CONTAINER

# Save image
docker save -o $CONTAINER.tar $CONTAINER

# Save the volumes (use ".tar.gz" if you want compression)
docker-volumes.sh $CONTAINER save $CONTAINER-volumes.tar

# Copy image and volumes to another host
scp $CONTAINER.tar $CONTAINER-volumes.tar $USER@$HOST:

# On the other host:
docker load -i $CONTAINER.tar
docker create --name $CONTAINER [<PREVIOUS CONTAINER OPTIONS>] $CONTAINER

# Load the volumes
docker-volumes.sh $CONTAINER load $CONTAINER-volumes.tar

# Start container
docker start $CONTAINER
```

Comment: Didn't work for me on AWS Linux (Centos).  In the endi I took the low tech approach of using docker inspect to find the volume dir, then manually copying that over.

Comment: @JasonPlutext Maybe something related to SELinux?  Do you have SELinux enabled?

Comment: Got this: tar: Removing leading `/' from member names

Comment: @hjahan That's a typical tar message.  Not an error and not an even a warning.

Comment: This worked very well, however I would recommend renaming the $CONTAINER to different names for the example. This is because the $CONTAINER name may not be the same as the actual CONTAINER image name. Also as a side note, You dont need to use `docker start` or `docker create` if using docker-compose. You can just use `docker-compose up` with the same config from the original system, then continue with the instructions.

Comment: Is this works on Raspberrypi os?

Comment: What is "<previous container options>"? Is there some way to find this out? I can't remember exactly how I created the container, it was years ago.

Answer (score 20):

From Docker documentation:

> `docker export` does not export the contents of volumes associated
>   with the  container. If a volume is mounted on top of an existing
>   directory in the container, `docker export` will export the contents
>   of the *underlying*  directory, not the contents of the volume. Refer
>   to [Backup, restore, or migrate data
>   volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes)
>   in the user guide for examples on exporting data in a volume.

Comment: cluster hq shutdown... and BTW to migrate container the container should run on ZFS / any supported storage lun

Answer (score 3):

I tried many solutions for this, and this is the one that worked for me :

1.commit/save container to new image :

1. ++ commit the container:
       *# docker stop 

       # docker commit CONTAINER_NAME 

       # docker save --output IMAGE_NAME.tar IMAGE_NAME:TAG*

ps:"Our container CONTAINER_NAME has a mounted volume at '/var/home'" ( you have to inspect your container to specify its volume path :  # docker inspect CONTAINER_NAME )

2. ++ save its volume : we will use an ubuntu image to do the thing.
       *# mkdir backup 

       # docker run --rm --volumes-from CONTAINER_NAME -v ${pwd}/backup:/backup ubuntu 
    bash -c “cd /var/home && tar  cvf  /backup/volume_backup.tar .”*

Now when you look at ${pwd}/backup , you will find our volume under tar format.
Until now, we have our conatainer's image 'IMAGE_NAME.tar' and its volume 'volume_backup.tar'.

Now you can , recreate the same old container on a new host.

Answer (score -1):

docker export | gzip > .tar.gz

#new host
gunzip < /mnt/usb/.tar.gz | docker import -

docker run -i -p 80:80  /bin/bash

Answer (score -1):

if you are using docker desktop you can use [this extension](https://hub.docker.com/extensions/docker/volumes-backup-extension)

or you can see [this link](https://www.docker.com/blog/back-up-and-share-docker-volumes-with-this-extension/) and describe **How does it work behind the scenes?** and do it by your self.