# Migrate container from one machine to another machine

Tags: docker, migration, export

I have setup docker in fedora23, I pull Ubuntu form docker hub and, Run a container then, installed LAMP server.

After installed LAMP Sever, then **Commit** my container following

```
docker commit  <container name> <image name >
```

Then **Save** image to tar.gz

```
docker save imagename > imagename.tar.gz
```

After Save the image, load to this **imagename.tar.gz** to load other machine. this docker images doesn't have LAMP Server, only have Fresh Ubuntu.

Suggest Me How to move docker image to other machine with changes.

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28734086/how-to-move-docker-containers-between-different-hosts

Comment: Use https://clusterhq.com/flocker/introduction/

Comment: @0aslam0  After commit my container only I send to another machine , It doesn' t have my change in this docker .,.

Comment: Did you read the related question. The LAMP you installed is in the data volume. You have to export your data volume to have it up and running