# Name a docker at build and how to retrieve it

Tags: docker

I tried to build a docker image. Then on docker images command, the list displays:

```
REPOSITORY     TAG        IMAGE ID            CREATED     SIZE  
<none>         <none>     eaaf8e203bd4        1 min ago   253.2 MB
```

Is there a way **in my Dockerfile to specify a name for this build**? Or at `docker build .` command line?

Another question: I want to upload via SFTP the docker container on my production server and run it. **Where are the containers stored?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `-t` option of [docker build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/)

```
docker build -t name:tag
```

The tag is optional.

> I want to upload via SFTP the docker container on my production server and run it.

You should "upload" the image, and by that I mean push it to a [docker registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/) running on your server.

You could also commit a running container into an intermediate image (which would freeze the running state of the container, but would not preserve the volume data, if one was declared in that container)
Then copy that archive, and [`docker import`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/import/) it.
See "[How to move docker containers between different hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28751780/6309)".

Once imported, see "[Where are docker images stored on the host machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19234831/6309)".
(`/var/lib/docker/containers` for containers)

Comment: @BlackHoleGalaxy no: when you build locally your image, you can name it as you want.

Comment: Thanks about this explaination.

Comment: @BlackHoleGalaxy I have edited the answer to address the second part of your question

Comment: And thanks again! I will look deeply toward private docker registry.