# How to build an image with a custom name?

Tags: docker

When I build an image using `docker build`:

```
docker build .
```

I get an image with a random name.

How to create a docker image with a custom name?

I already know how to set the name in the [`Dockerfile`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38986057/how-to-set-image-name-in-dockerfile), but I'm not sure how to use it in the `build` command.

Comment: I'm posting this following to [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361666/technically-off-topic-answer-but-seems-to-be-helpful?noredirect=1#comment546609_361666).

Comment: This is somewhat deceptive, as the answer to "how do set the image name in the Dockerfile?" is **you can't**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Name a docker at build and how to retrieve it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41621672/name-a-docker-at-build-and-how-to-retrieve-it)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use the `-t` flag, as shown in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#tag-an-image--t) (or run `docker build --help` to learn about the options you have).

You should do:

```
docker build -t my-image .
```

Now the image is created with the name `my-image`:

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                  TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
my-image                    latest              43070bef9dfa        2 minutes ago       464MB
```