# Exporting a container created with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a series of containers created with **docker-compose**. Some of these containers communicate between each other with some rules defined in the **docker-compose.yml** file.

I need to move those containers from a *serverA* to *serverB* (same OS) but i'm having issues in understanding how this works.

I tried both with the **export** and the **save** methods following tutorials i've found on the web but I was not able to get the port configurations and networking rules after the *export* - *import* or *save* - *load* operations (there's a chance I didn't really get how they work...)

The only way I've found to succesfully do this is to copy the whole docker-compose folder and run *docker-compose up* in serverB.

**The question:**

Is there a way to preserve the whole configuration of the containers and move them from a server to another using the export or save function?

Thank you for any help you can provide

Comment: "Why do you want to move it from one server to the other?" - The answer to this question would help me answer your query better. What's your end goal?

Comment: Similar question [How to move Docker containers between different hosts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28734086/8482479)

Comment: Best practice would be the thing you did that works, `docker push` your images to a registry, copy the `docker-compose.yml` file to the other system, and run `docker-compose up` there.  Don't worry about the specific containers as entities, and avoid `export` or `save` operations.

Comment: @7_R3X 
mostly.. learning purposes

Comment: @b0gusb
I know that one. Tried exactly every solutions included but I didn't get the port configuration to preserve.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for your answer! I'll try as you suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 scenarios:

### Copy via ssh

```
$ sudo docker save  myImage:tag | ssh user@IPhost:/remote/dir docker load -
```

### Copy via scp

```
#Host A
$ docker save Image > myImage.tar
$ scp myImage.tar IPhostB:/tmp/myImage.tar
# Host B
$ docker load -i /tmp/myImage.tar
```

And then you need to copy the docker-compose.yml to the host B too.

The containers only have the original build's own configurations, but they don't save the environment that we generate with the file docker-compose.yml

Bye

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. Everything worked flawlessy ( apart from the POSTGRE database, but i'll open a different question for this one since seems like there could be a different procedure!)