# Docker move/export docker-compose container to another machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am a beginner with docker and have created a docker-compose.yml file. Everything is running well, but I want to move my container that is generated by "docker-compose up" to another machine. How can I save/export my container that is running my services of the docker-compose.yml to another machine?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at these 2 questions: [How to copy Docker images from one host to another without using a repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935141/how-to-copy-docker-images-from-one-host-to-another-without-using-a-repository), [How to move Docker containers between different hosts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28734086/how-to-move-docker-containers-between-different-hosts) because it seems that you need something similar

Comment: @tgogos ok, so my docker-compose creates an image for each service inside the yml file and thus I need to save every image created? Docker-compose build doesn't generate a single image that I can save?

Answer (score 3):

For commit running container to image with new tag you can use this command :

```
$ docker commit <containerID> new_image_name:tag
```

For save new_image_name:tag to file use :

```
$ docker save -o new_file_name.tar new_image_name:tag
```

Now you can move your **docker-compose.yml** to same folder to another machine and your **new_file_name.tar** too.
On your mother machine where are this files run :

```
$ docker load --input new_file_name.tar
```

Rewrite in docker-compose.yml section *image:* to your new_image_name:tag

If you lost the name use :

```
$ docker images
```

and continue with *$ docker load.....* from above

Last step is run :

```
$ docker-compose up -d
```