# How to backup stopped docker container files to remote machine

Tags: docker

I have a docker container (for example named as rocky_85) occupied around 130 GB disk space. The disk space only left around 20GB.
So, "docker commit" failed because disk full.

Also docker restart the container is impossible, because my other docker container have already start with the same export port (for example 8080).

Is there any method to backup the stopped container rocky_85 to remote machine's larger disk space? Or other mount disk point?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move Docker containers between different hosts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28734086/how-to-move-docker-containers-between-different-hosts)

Comment: `docker commit` is almost never a best practice.  A container is a wrapper around a _process_ and I wouldn't normally expect it to need to be backed up.  Whatever data needs to be persisted, can you store it in a volume or bind mount, and back _that_ up instead?